# Sharing Code between eclipse and intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I work with a partner in java programming, I use intellij and he uses Eclipse. 
Is there a way that we can somehow mutually share our code with each other so we could work on the same code each in our own time?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control

Answer (score 0):

There is that possibility using `GIT` or another Code repository. Look at https://github.com/
or https://bitbucket.org/.  There is also very helpfull [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/18/the-top-7-open-source-version-control-systems/). 
To be also independant you can simply integrate your code with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), both incellij and eclipse can import project based only on `pom.xml` file created in maven setup.

Answer (score 0):

In this your should use repository when there are more than one programmer  on a single project whether you are using even same IDE. SVN will be one of the choices for repository

Answer (score 0):

Given that you guys need to implement version control, one important aspect of co-operating together is to keep your codebase *IDE-agnostic*.

Thankfully, with java and maven there is an easy way to do this.

Firstly, commit to building your project with a build tool such as maven. Therefore, using this example, the **pom.xml** is the master configuration file for your project.

In contrast, your "project" files (either your `.idea` folder for intellij or your `.project`, `.classpath` and related files for eclipse) should not be checked into version control at all.

You can then add "ignores" to your VCS so that IDE-specific configuration files are not checked in - this way you won't interfere with each other with IDE-specific things.

Then, it is relatively easy for both of you to share a maven (pom.xml) based project with each other, and to configure your IDE independently from each other (i.e.: locally).